# Integrate Facebook connect with PEAR Auth class?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, pear

I am using the monolith PEAR Auth class on my site for authentication, but recently I've decided that Facebook connect would be ideal as well for my site. I've been on the Facebook dev website which provides examples to integrate Facebook with current classes, but I don't want to modify the PEAR Auth repository I have on my server.

Is there another solution? Should I integrate another Auth system?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement your own Facebook container for PEAR Auth. You do not need to modify PEAR's auth code for that, because it tries to load the authentication container from your include path.

Suppose you have PEAR installed in `/usr/share/php/`, and your app in `/var/www/myapp/`, you could create a file `/var/www/myapp/src/Auth/Container/Facebook.php`. In your app, use

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/myapp/src/')
```

to make PEAR Auth recognize your custom container directory. Then you can instantiate a facebook container in Auth

Comment: btw, if you haven't already dismissed this thread. Can the container's path be any where? Or does it have to be relative to or in the path where Auth is found?

"var/www/myapp/src/Auth/Containter"

or

"var/www/myapp/php/Auth/Container" <-- where the Auth repo is

Necessary or not?

Comment: you need to follow the PEAR Auth class structure, so you class needs to be named Auth_Container_Something - the class name also determines the file name, replace _ with / and append a .php